# how can i set username and password for basic http authentication?

Tags: perl, http, authentication, cgi, basic-authentication

i have a perl programm and used from cgi on it.i append the below line to the code

```
use CGI qw(:cgi);
print header(-type => 'text/html', -status => '401 Not Authorized',
         'WWW-Authenticate' => 'Basic realm="Videos"');
```

and when i enter the url browser wants username and password from me.problem is that i dont know what is user and password and where should i assign them.
also any help with another mechanism to provide basic authentication would be good.
can anyone help me with this?
thanks.

Comment: So … you do not know which user and password to provide for which **you** are asking in the first place?

Comment: @serenesat: Ooh look. Here's another. You could actually do something useful this time too

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Normally the webserver handles the basic authentication, and then it would probably also handle returning 401 for unauthorised requests - so your code id probably pointless.

If you really want to try doing it yourself, you'll also have to parse the headers the browser sends when the user has tried to authenticate, validate the informatin using whatever method you like and return a useable page if successful.

Comment: thanks @Henrik.your answer help me to understand what really is authentication.i do what you said and place my code here.

Comment: can you tell me how get the request header from browser?i get it by ENV variable but authentication box doesnt disappear.

Answer (score 0):

Since you're already using CGI, you could drop in the [CGI::Auth::Basic](http://search.cpan.org/dist/CGI-Auth-Basic-1.22/lib/CGI/Auth/Basic.pm) module from CPAN.  Or if you need something more featured, [CGI::Auth](http://search.cpan.org/~ccwallace/CGI-Auth-3.00/Auth.pm)

Comment: i tried this module at the first time but it sends me an eror at line 314 of the module!!